# Real-life application of min(X,Y) series system

Tags: probability, reliability

Let $X$ and $Y$ be the random variables. What are the real life situations where $\min(X,Y)$ arises?

Comment: Do not cross-post: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3317016/321264.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two elementary examples, involving exponential models. Exponential models are widely used in queueing theory and in reliability theory.

**(1) Waiting for service.** Your bank has 2 tellers with one waiting line. You are the next person in
line to be served. Tellers have exponentially distributed service rates of
$\lambda_1 = 5$ and $\lambda_2 = 6$ customers per hour. How long on average before you will get to start your service with the first available teller.

***Simulated answer:*** About 0.091 hours or 5.46 minutes.

```
set.seed(1234)
x = rexp(10^6, 5);  y = rexp(10^6, 6)
w = pmin(x, y)
mean(w)
[1] 0.09097995
```

***Theoretical:*** Using CDF's it is not difficult to show that $$W = \min(X,Y) \sim \mathsf{Exp}(\text{rate} = 6+5=11).$$ By the no-memory property of exponential models, your exponential waiting time begins when you get to the head of the line, so the average wait is $E(W) = 1/11$ hr.

**(2) Useful life of a space probe.** A space probe has two computers. The mission will be completely successful only if both computers survive. Given information on the lifetime distributions of the two computers, what is the probability one of the computers will fail before
the end of a planned 5 year mission.

***Theoretical answer:*** Suppose each computer fails (independently) at an exponential rate, each surviving on average 10 years. The distribution of the time to failure of the first computer is exponential with rate 1/5 per year. Then $P(W \le 5) = 1 - e^{-1} = 0.6321.$

***Simulated:***

```
set.seed(2019)
x = rexp(10^6, .1);  y = rexp(10^6, .1)
w = pmin(x,y)
mean(w < 5)
[1] 0.631415
```

[image]